# How to create a new window with text and an image

Tags: javascript, html, image, testing, window

Here is my code, I want to add a picture below this:

```
function createWindow() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=500,height=500");
    myWindow.document.write("<h1>A test: </h1>" + 
    " <p> <b>Something bold: </b> text </p>");
    // I want to add an image here (inside the widow) but I'm not sure how

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `<img src="imagesource">`?

Comment: document.write can be avoided. You can load a html file in window.open by passing url

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image to your html document of `myWindow` like this:

```js
myWindow.document.write("<img src='https://i.imgur.com/RUKhJjI.png' width=256 height=256>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function createWindow() {
  const myWindow = window.open('', 'My New Window', 'width=500,height=500')
  myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = `
    <h1>A test:</h1>
    <p> <b>Something bold: </b> text </p>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qVr8o7q.jpeg" />
  `;
}
```